# Save a JPG without a background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, jpg, background-removal

I have created this image in Photoshop:

[image]

Layers:

[image]

I would like to save this arrow to a .jpg file without the white background rectangle. How can I achieve that? I was trying to hide the background layer before saving, but this doesn't help.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy format. Saving anything as a .jpg will deteriorate the quality. This is not a big problem for photos, but for graphics like this it will be very noticeable. Use PNG or some other lossless format for graphics.

Comment: Beyond the fact that you need to use PNG rather than JPEG to have transparency, I would strongly recommend you use AI rather than Photoshop and save the file as SVG. This way, you'll get transparency **and** you'll get a vector file, which can be scaled at will without resolution loss. This is especially useful if you intend to use the graphic on a website or an app which could be viewed on Retina / HiDPI displays.

Comment: To add to the other replies, I want to note that this image really shoukd be png (not jpeg) *anyway*. The sharp edges and lack of continuous toning will be bad for jpeg and compress very well as png.

Comment: what is that; an ink blot?

Comment: A JPEG image does not have a background - the picture is stored as a monolithic image. It is more of a compression format and, as @Suppen commented, is lossy, which means some data may be lost without seriously degrading the image's recognition (by a human).

Comment: @RonRoyston looks kinda like a clock face which collapsed. Maybe it's a logo for the company which builds TARDISes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can't save transparency to a .jpg. The file format simply doesn't support it. Anything that is transparent will become white when saved to a .jpeg.

Try .png or .gif, those file formats *do* accept transparency.

Comment: Keep in mind there are two types of PNG, PNG-8 and PNG-24. PNG-8 basically has transparency as a "color", so a pixel is either transparent or not. PNG-24 has a 256-level alpha, so you can have semi-transparent pixels; for anti-aliased graphics (which it looks like OP's is), PNG-24 is the better bet. GIF operates like PNG-8, so the same applies.

Comment: @DoktorJ not true: an indexed PNG can have alpha values on any or all of the palette entires. It’s in a separate table so you might have overlooked it: that saves space as you don’t need 4 bytes for *every* palete entry.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47458/discussion-on-answer-by-vincent-save-a-jpg-without-a-background).

Answer (score 6):

jPeg images save automatically with a flat solid background. You will be able to achieve saving your image with a transparent background to .png format.

It won't work with JPEG format.

Some reference to assist [transparent background](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1045381)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can't make a JPG transparent. However, your reason for wanting it to be transparent is important for determining what format to use. For vector graphics, for example, EPS allows a clipping mask to mask out the background, and that format can used to place a graphic on a background in a layout program like InDesign, for example. That is why EPS is a preferred format for vector graphics to be used in print layouts. For other uses, the format, and the way the final image is composed, are both important.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the background layer first. Then try "Ctrl+ Shift + Alt + S" to save for web and choose png. Or just save as and choose png as your filetype.

Answer (score 0):

Opt for PNG32 which allows for full alpha transparency. That's what I use.

Comment: Hi wh1974, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!